# Using OAUTH API with CURL on a PHP page

Tags: php, curl, oauth, php-curl

I'm working with a PHP website where I want to integrate to some 3rd party API.

In particular I am looking at using CURL to interact with their server but this is something I am far from an expert in so hoping the community can help me gain a better understanding of what I am doing.

I am unclear what options such as -X and -d do, also I am unclear how I script this command on my PHP page?  (Unfortunately it's tricky searching google for "-d" as this isn't considered part of the search string)

My particular example I am stuck on is requesting an access token, the API documentation provided to me is;

```
curl -X POST \
-d \ "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&scope=REQUESTED_SCOPES" \
'https://api.example.com/token'
```

> grant_type- client_credentials
>
> client_id- Generated during setup
>
> client_secret - Web apps only, generated during setup
>
> scope Optional - List of comma separated values, see supported scopes
>
> If the request is successful, an access token will be returned in the
>   response:

```
 {
"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600
"scope":"REQUEST_SCOPES"
}
```

That is the above guidance, I have completed the pre-requisites so can confirm the client id, secret and required scope are correct.

I have tried both of the following in vein in my PHP script

```
$tk = curl_init();

curl_setopt($tk, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.example.com/token");
curl_setopt($tk, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($tk, CURL_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($tk, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myownid&client_secret=xyz123&scope=instrument'));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result=curl_exec($tk);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($tk);
```

And

```
$tk = curl_init();

curl_setopt($tk, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.example.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myownid&client_secret=xyz123&scope=instrument");
curl_setopt($tk, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($tk, CURL_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result=curl_exec($tk);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($tk);
```

Both of these examples produce the following error;

> {"error_description":"grant_type parameter is
>   missing","error":"invalid_request"}

Any help on this particular issue or even to just understand how I am going wrong to give me some ideas of the correct syntax will be much appreciated!

Thank you all in advanced for your time.

- (Please note I've changed to "example.com" for security of the 3rd
  party)

Comment: _“I am unclear what options such as -X and -d do”_ - then start here, https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json` is definitively wrong - nothing in the original cURL command shown as example, has anything whatsoever to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out below sample code of cURL call in php. You need to change your domain name instead of example.com also put values for POSTFIELDS.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/oauth/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\",\"client_id\": \"YOUR_CLIENT_ID\",\"client_secret\": \"YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET\",\"scope\": \"instrument\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it OO instead of using cURL, you might like this better. First up require in Guzzle:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Create an ApiCredentials Object:

```
<?php

namespace Some\Company;

class ApiCredentials
{
    private $clientKey;

    private $clientSecret;

    private $proxy;

    private $baseUrl;

    public function __construct(string $clientKey, string $clientSecret, string $proxy = '', string $baseUrl = 'https://api.somewhere.com')
    {
        $this->clientKey = $clientKey;
        $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;
        $this->proxy = $proxy;
        $this->baseUrl = $baseUrl;
    }

    public function getClientKey(): string
    {
        return $this->clientKey;
    }

    public function getClientSecret(): string
    {
        return $this->clientSecret;
    }

    public function getProxy(): string
    {
        return $this->proxy;
    }

    public function getBaseUrl(): string
    {
        return $this->baseUrl;
    }
}
```

Now create an ApiService class:

```
<?php

namespace Some\Company;

use DateTime;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiService
{
    const API_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = '/token';

    private $baseUrl;

    private $client;

    private $accessToken;

    private $credentials;

    public function __construct(ApiCredentials $credentials)
    {
        $this->baseUrl = $credentials->getBaseUrl();
        $options = $this->initOptions($credentials);
        $this->client = new Client($options);
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
    }

    private function initOptions(ApiCredentials $credentials) : array
    {
        $options = [
            'base_uri' => $this->baseUrl,
            'verify'  => false,
        ];
        if ($credentials->getProxy() !== '') {
            $options = \array_merge($options, ['proxy' => [
                'https' => $credentials->getProxy(),
            ]]);
        }

        return $options;
    }

    private function hasAccessToken() : bool
    {
        return $this->accessToken instanceof AccessToken && $this->accessToken->getExpires() > new DateTime();
    }

    private function getAccessToken() : AccessToken
    {
        return $this->accessToken;
    }

    private function getCredentials(): ApiCredentials
    {
        return $this->credentials;
    }

    private function refreshAccessToken()
    {
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $response = $client->post(
            $this->baseUrl . self::API_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
                'client_id' => $this->getCredentials()->getClientKey(),
                'client_secret' => $this->getCredentials()->getClientSecret(),
                'scope' => 'put your scopes in here',
            ],
        ]);
        $json = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $this->accessToken = new AccessToken($json);
    }

    private function getClient() : Client
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    private function validateToken()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAccessToken()) {
            $this->refreshAccessToken();
        }
    }

    public function getSomeEndpointData(string $someParam = 'whatever') : string
    {
        $this->validateToken();

        $response = $this->getClient()->get(
            $this->baseUrl . '/get/some/data/' . $someParam, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken()->getToken(),
            ],
            'query' => [
                'additional' => 'this creates stuff like ?additional=whatever',
            ],
        ]);
        $json = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        return $json;
    }

}
```

And an access token class:

```
<?php

namespace Some\Company;

use DateTime;

class AccessToken
{
    private $token;

    private $scope;

    private $type;

    private $expires;

    public function __construct(string $tokenJson)
    {
        $token = \json_decode($tokenJson, true);
        $keys = [
            'access_token', 'scope', 'token_type', 'expires_in',
        ];

        $this->token = $token['access_token'];
        $this->scope = $token['scope'];
        $this->type = $token['token_type'];
        $date = new DateTime('+' .$token['expires_in'] . ' seconds');
        $this->expires = $date;
    }

    public function getToken(): string
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    public function getScope(): string
    {
        return $this->scope;
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function getExpires(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->expires;
    }
}
```

Now, to use this stuff:

```
<?php

use Some\Company\ApiCredentials;
use Some\Company\ApiService;

$clientKey = 'client key key here';
$clientSecret = 'client secret here';
$proxy = 'tcp://199.199.132.132:80'; // optional

$creds = new ApiCredentials($clientKey, $clientSecret, $proxy);
$apiService = new ApiService($creds);

$results = $apiService->getSomeEndpointData('whatever'); // returns json
```

It will handle refreshing access tokens etc too.